# BeautifulSoup with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn beautifulsoup to scrap HTML and have a difficult challenge. HTML I am trying to scrap is not well formatted and with lack of knowledge with beautifulsoup I am kind of stuck..

The HTML I am trying to scrap is as below

```
 *<tr class="unique">
                    <td>S.N.</td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/stock-name/desc/" class="icon-asc sorter">Traded Companies</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/transaction/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">No. Of Transaction</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/max-price/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">Max Price</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/min-price/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">Min Price</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/closing-price/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">Closing Price</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/total-share/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">Traded Shares</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/amount/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">Amount</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/previous-closing/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">Previous Closing</a></td>
                    <td class="alnright"><a href="http://www.nepalstock.com/main/todays_price/index/1/difference/asc/" class="icon-sorter sorter">Difference Rs.</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Agriculture Development Bank Limited</td>
                    <td class="alnright">47</td>
                    <td class="alnright">437.00</td>
                    <td class="alnright">426.00</td>
                    <td class="alnright">435.00</td>
                    <td class="alnright">9725.00</td>
                    <td class="alnright">4204614.00</td>
                    <td class="alnright">431.00</td>
                    <td class="alnright">4.00&nbsp;
                        <img src="http://www.nepalstock.com/images/increase.gif">
                    </td>
                </tr>*
```

So the outcome I want to get is the string "Agriculture Development Bank Limited". 
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: please post your code and the url that you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Currently this should work for you `soup.find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')[1].text.strip()`

Comment: I am trying to scrape from this url.. Trying to get all the trading companies list. nepalstock.com/todaysprice . – bijay subedi  @SagunShrestha

Answer (score 0):

Can help you more precisely if you ask it in general what are you looking for. Here is the code which will satisfy your this need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """
Your HTML code
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find("td", text="Agriculture Development Bank Limited").text
```